# How do you properly discern between these quantification sentences?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

The first sentence being something like
$$\text{For all $x$, $P(x)$}$$
meaning that $P$ for any $x$.
And the second
$$\text{(For all $x$ such that $P(x)$})\dots Q(x)$$
supposed to mean that $Q$ only for the $x$ for $P$. How do you formalize this? How do you write this in terms of the symbols appearing in FO logic? Is this the above even a "right" way to write those two notions? And is the latter statement really saying
$$
\forall x \in \{s|P(s)\} \dots 
$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the second, you can phrase it as $(\forall x)~P(x)\implies \cdots$ with an implication.

Comment: The first one says that everything is a P...

Comment: The second one says that every P is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what comes after the ellipsis. By itself "For all x $P(x)$" can be written as  $\forall x, P(x)$ and this means that for each $x$, $P(x)$ is true. However if you put the words "implies $Q(x)$" after the ellipsis in the first phrase then you have $\forall x, P(x)\implies Q(x)$ which can be written as "For all x such that $P(x), Q(x)$". This latter expression means $\forall x,\neg{(Q(x)\wedge (\neg(P(x))}$, which is clearly different from $\forall x, P(x)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer